# 404 Error In Magento Admin Controller

Tags: magento-1.9

I have been getting 404 error in Magento Admin Controller and i cant seem to figure out what i am doing wrong:

I have this in the config.xml

```
<!--Admin Controller-->
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <example before="Mage_Adminhtml">MasteringMagento_Example_Adminhtml
                    </example>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

I have this inside my controllers/Adminhtml/ExampleController.php

```
class MasteringMagento_Example_Adminhtml_ExampleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function indexAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
    return $this->renderLayout();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by changing the Admin Route in the config.hml to this:

```
    <!--Admin Controller-->
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <MasteringMagento_Example before="Mage_Adminhtml">MasteringMagento_Example_Adminhtml</MasteringMagento_Example>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept your own answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try:**

```
<admin>
    <routers>
      <example>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>MasteringMagento_Example</module>
          <frontName>admin_example</frontName>
        </args>
      </example>
    </routers>
  </admin>
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class MasteringMagento_Example_Adminhtml_ExamplebackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        //return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('example/examplebackend');
        return true;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
       $this->loadLayout();
       $this->_title($this->__("Backend Page Title"));
       $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```